# TV movie - some kind of secret agent who had total recall

Tags: story-identification, tv

I can only remember one scene where he is trapped under a tractor in a corn field and remembers the technical blueprint of the tractor and disables it.

It might be called something like "Man from Omega."

Comment: FOUND IT!!  The Delphi Bureau.

Comment: Since there's no sign of @steve, I've added the answer as a community Wiki.

Answer (score 5):

Per @steve's comment, the answer is "[The Delphi Bureau](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068474/)". The tractor scene was seen in the pilot movie.

The scene is described (in astonishing detail) in this [review by Rick G](http://www.redpowermagazine.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=60907&page=6).

> Yes, the name of the movie is "The Delphi Bureau" made in 1972. The
>   agent with the photographic memory was played by actor Laurence
>   Luckinbill. The tractor in the movie was an IH 856 if memory serves.
>   The 856 got quite a bit of screen time, with the bad guy chasing the
>   good guy agent around the field for a while, before finally running
>   said good guy down, only to prolong the scene even more showing good
>   guy hanging on to the frame under the tractor to keep from getting run
>   over by the disk. (highly improbable after being struck and knocked
>   down by the front axle). Then his photographic memory kicks in, and he
>   reaches up and pulls off a fuel line, killing the tractor. That scene
>   of him pulling off a rubber fuel line was contrived and shot as a
>   close up, preventing the viewer from seeing the tractor at all. It was
>   inaccurate at that point and not even a real 856 fuel line.
>
> I also seem to remember that the engine sound was dubbed for whatever
>   reason, and was not the actual sound of a D 407 in an 856! How dumb,
>   why would they do that? Well, the whole movie was pretty hokie as I
>   remember... But the highlight was watching that 856, ha....

Comment: ^_^ Sounds like the use of incorrect tractor details really offended the reviewer...

Comment: @SeanDuggan - The original quote doesn't do his indignation justice. I've added the rest.